# Swift AudioKit Unable to set Input Device

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I'm trying to use AudioKit v5.6.1 to read from the microphone, but I am struggling to set the input device of AudioEngine. I am testing on an iPhone 12 mini running iOS 16.4 and Xcode v14.3. Here is the code I'm testing out:
import Foundation
import AudioKit

```
public class AudioService {
    
    public static let instance = AudioService()
    
    private let engine: AudioEngine
    
    private init () {
        
        engine = AudioEngine()
        
        guard !engine.avEngine.isRunning else {
            print("Audio engine is already running")
            return
        }
        
        guard case let inputs = AudioEngine.inputDevices, inputs.isNotEmpty else {
            print("Could not find any input devices")
            return
        }
        
        let input = inputs[0]
        
        try! AudioEngine.setInputDevice(input)
        
        
    }
}
```

I'm simply initialising this service in a View currently:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    
    let audioService = AudioService.instance
    
    var body: some View {
        ...
    }
}
```

However, when I call AudioEngine.setInputDevice, I receive this error `Foundation._GenericObjCError.nilError`, but have confirmed that `input` is not nil. It has `name = "iPhone Microphone"` and `deviceID = "Built-In Microphone Bottom"`. Any help with this would be appreciated because looking at the AudioKit cookbook, I don't see what I can do differently.

Answer (score 0):

Immediately after posting this I found that I had a typo in my Info.plist where I should have put NSMicrophoneUsageDescription. The code runs after fixing this.